# SQL WHERE date partially field and partially predefined string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For my project we are using MS SQL 2008. In an subquery i like to search in an WHERE clause to the last day of the current (in the SQL loop) year. It should be something like:

```
WHERE datefieldsubquery = currentyearparentquery+'-12-31 23:59:00'
```

But there is no output in the subquery while using this. When the query is for example:

```
WHERE datefieldsubquery = '2014-12-31 23:59:00'
```

the query returns an result. I like that '2014' is dynamically inherited from the parent query. Is that possible in SQL?

-- edit --
Both fields are datetime.

Real complete query:

```
   SELECT factuurregel.[Internal costkind] AS code,
    COUNT(factuurregel.[Internal costkind]) AS total,
    YEAR(factuurregel.[Invoice date lease company]) AS maand,                       
    (
      SELECT COUNT(leasecontract.[Contract Ending Date]) AS autos 
      FROM [test$Lease Contract] AS leasecontract                   
      WHERE (leasecontract.[Status] = '0' OR leasecontract.[Status] = '1') 
      AND YEAR(leasecontract.[Contract Activation Date]) <= YEAR(factuurregel.[Invoice date lease company])
      AND (YEAR(leasecontract.[Contract Ending Date]) > YEAR(factuurregel.[Invoice date lease company]) 
      OR leasecontract.[Contract Ending Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00')                                                  
    ) AS autos
    FROM [test$Invoice line] AS factuurregel
    LEFT JOIN [test$Lease Car] AS leasecar ON factuurregel.[License No_] = leasecar.[License No_]
    WHERE factuurregel.[Internal costkind] >= '200' 
    AND factuurregel.[Internal costkind] < '300'
    AND (leasecar.[Licence Type] = 1 OR leasecar.[Licence Type] = 2)
    GROUP BY YEAR(factuurregel.[Invoice date lease company]),factuurregel.[Internal costkind]
    ORDER BY factuurregel.[Internal costkind]
```

Comment: How about `WHERE year(datefieldsubquery) < currentyearparentquery+1`?

Comment: What are your data types? Is datefieldsubquery a date? datetime? varchar? Is currentyearparentquery an integer? varchar? What you ask is possible, but we need more detail to help you.

Comment: what is currentyearparentquery in your query ?

Comment: Please edit your question with the query you are using -- or a simplified version thereof.  It is really hard to suggest anything, because there is not enough information.

Comment: @Robert: Both fields are datetime.

Comment: @juergen that is indeed the solution in this case. But when using another moment in the year i need to use 1 date. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way in your `WHERE` Clause

```
WHERE datefieldsubquery = Convert(varchar(50),YEAR(GETDATE()))+'-12-31 23:59:00'
```

Comment: This solution workd for me! String conversation is the solution.